# Is spring-data-rest-webmvc:3.4.x compatible with Spring Boot 2.3.x?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

There is a vulnerability (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-22047) discovered in `spring-data-rest-webmvc` which is only fixed in versions `3.4.14` and `3.5.6`. Spring Boot `2.3.12` uses the version `3.3.9`. Migrating to spring boot `2.4.x` or above is not an option for us.
We would like to use `spring-data-rest-webmvc:3.4.14`, but we are not sure if it's compatible with spring boot `2.3.x`.
Can we use them together?

Comment: Spring Data Rest uses Spring 5.3 whereas Spring Boot 2.3 uses Spring 5.2. Will it work it might, any garanties no due to the different Spring version being used.

Comment: Consider adding this as an answer so that it can be accepted and the question closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Rest version 3.4 and up use Spring Framework version 5.3.x.

Spring Boot 2.3 is build with Spring Framework 5.2.x.

Will it work, probably, but there are no garanties that it will keep working or work at all. Most like it will fail with some `NoSuchMethodError` or `ClassNotFOundExceptions` or other exotic expetions one gets when mixing modules/jars from different versions of a framework.